# How to find the associated apple-id for each app in your iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I have inherited an iPhone with many predecessors. Wasn't reset in the middle. Had multiple id's and applications installed. 
I want to see a list of applications with the id that was used to install it, so that I can go about removing all apps not from my apple-id and reinstall them using my apple-id

```
+--------------+------------------------+
|   Appname    |        AppleID         |
+--------------+------------------------+
| Goodreads    | someemail@icloud.com   |
| Trello       | predecessor@icloud.com |
| findmyiphone | thief@icloud.com       |
| MangaRock    | otaku@icloud.com       |
| kindle       | someemail@icloud.com   |
+--------------+------------------------+
```

...etc. You get the idea, it can be any email address.

I know it would be simpler to just reset and install only my own apps, but then I'm using a lot of the other apps,  and want to know what they are so that I can install them.

You can get this information for one app at a time, via this method: http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/answers/how_to_locate_the_apple_id_associated_with_an_ios_app
However, that doesn't help when you have 200+ apps. 
The data must be in the .itl file, as I searched the library.xml with no luck in finding the associated appleid